# Category url different in newly created storeview!

Tags: magento-1.9

I have a store-view for the Hebrew language. In which, category URL using the suffix `.html`.

for example- http://www.example.com/store/index.php/language/category.html

Now, I have created new store-view for another language In which category URL are not the same, default category URL(with category id) is using in newly created store-view.

for example- http://www.example.com/store/index.php/new_language/catalog/category/view/s/cream-filled-desserts/id/153/

How can I add the same category URL with `.html` suffix for newly created store-view.

I am using magento 1.9.0.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you reindexed, after creating the new store view?

On the server, from the Magento root, run the following:

`php shell/indexer.php reindexall`

Then, flush cache and test.

Comment: The issue has been fixed, it was the re-indexing issue.

Answer (score 1):

After to selecting store view from admin panel > catalog > Manage categories you need to uncheck the "URL Key" checkbox and save it. Then you need to reindex and clear the cache. It will work.